# How to make JTable both AutoResize and horizontall scrollable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, autoresize

I am putting a JTable into a JScrollPane

But When I set JTable Auto Resizeable, then it won't have horizontal scroll bar.

if I set AUTO_RESIZE_OFF, then the Jtable won't fill the width of its container when the column width is not big enough.

So how can I do this:

1. when the table is not wide enough, expand to fill its container width
2. when the table is wide enough, make it scrollable.

Thanks

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to customize the behaviour of the Scrollable interface.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableHorizontal extends JFrame
{
    public TableHorizontal()
    {
        final JTable table = new JTable(10, 5)
        {
            public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth()
            {
                return getPreferredSize().width < getParent().getWidth();
            }
        };
        table.setAutoResizeMode( JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF );
        final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        getContentPane().add( scrollPane );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TableHorizontal frame = new TableHorizontal();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The above code basically sizes the component at its preferred size or the viewport size, whichever is greater.

Comment: excelent knowledge +1, for setSize -1

Comment: ahhh ... Row, your trick - should have guessed so much :-) But it's uncomplete, hampers resizing of columns, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/15499255/203657

Comment: @kleopatra, I learn as I answer more questions (and see other answers). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234691/enabling-auto-resize-of-jtable-only-if-it-fit-viewport/15240806#15240806 for an updated approach.

Answer (score 11):

If for some reason customising JTable is not an option (e.g. it might be created in third-party code), you can achieve the same result by setting it to toggle between two different JTable AUTO_RESIZE modes whenever the containing viewport is resized, e.g.:

```
jTable.getParent().addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void componentResized(final ComponentEvent e) {
        if (jTable.getPreferredSize().width < jTable.getParent().getWidth()) {
            jTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
        } else {
            jTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you for the simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

I found that all that is needed is to include

```
  table = new JTable(model);
  // this enables horizontal scroll bar
  table.setAutoResizeMode( JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF );
```

and then when the required viewport width and height have been calculated, include

```
  frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table))
  table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(width,height));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the Layout of its container to [BorderLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) with a [BorderLayout.CENTER](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html#CENTER) layout constraint, then the JTable will auto resize to fit its container.

If you want to make a component scrollable, you can wrap the JTable with a [JScrollPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html).

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
add(new JScrollPane(new JTable()), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: This only auto resizes for the width not height. How can I make it auto resize the height?