# JScrollPane not working horizontally

Tags: java, jscrollpane, horizontal-scrolling

[image]

Hi. I need some help. JScrollPane working vertically good but horizontally not. And I cant find whats the problem. I know that its a little big project and there is a lot of confusing codes but I cant delete any of that function.

```
public final class Salary extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private SalaryTableModel tableModel;
public int selectedRow = -1;
public static String bolme;
public static String ay;
public static int il = 0;
private final String selectedItem_Bolme;
private final String selectedItem_Ay;
private final int selectedItem_Il;
private List<Pojo> sortedList;
public TableColumn date;
public static int bolmeId = 0;
public static String ad;
public static int row2;

public void visible(String bolme2, String ay2, int il2) {
    il = il2;
    ay = ay2;
    bolme = bolme2;
    new Salary().setVisible(true);
}

public RXTable autoResizeColWidth(RXTable table, SalaryTableModel model) {
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    table.setModel(model);
    int margin = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        int vColIndex = i;
        DefaultTableColumnModel colModel = (DefaultTableColumnModel) table.getColumnModel();
        TableColumn col = colModel.getColumn(vColIndex);
        int width;
        TableCellRenderer renderer = col.getHeaderRenderer();
        if (renderer == null) {
            renderer = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
        }
        Component comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, col.getHeaderValue(), false, false, 0, 0);
        width = comp.getPreferredSize().width;
        for (int r = 0; r < table.getRowCount(); r++) {
            renderer = table.getCellRenderer(r, vColIndex);
            comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, table.getValueAt(r, vColIndex), false, false,
                    r, vColIndex);
            width = Math.max(width, comp.getPreferredSize().width);
        }
        width += 2 * margin;
        col.setPreferredWidth(width);
    }
    ((DefaultTableCellRenderer) table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer()).setHorizontalAlignment(
            SwingConstants.LEFT);
    table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    return table;
}

public Salary() {
    initComponents();
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/images/db.png"));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    List<Pojo> model = DBO.findBolme();
    HashSet hs = new HashSet();
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    model.stream().forEach((model1) -> {
        hs.add(model1.getBolme());
    });
    al.addAll(hs);
    comboBolme.addItem("Butun Bolmeler");
    al.stream().forEach((al1) -> {
        comboBolme.addItem(al1);
        bolmeId++;
    });
    comboBolme.removeItem("null");
    if (bolme == null) {
        comboBolme.setSelectedIndex(0);
    } else {
        comboBolme.setSelectedItem(bolme);
    }

    if (ay == null) {
        comboAy.setSelectedIndex(0);
    } else {
        comboAy.setSelectedItem(ay);
    }

    List<Pojo> model2 = DBO.findIl();
    HashSet hs2 = new HashSet();
    ArrayList al2 = new ArrayList();
    model2.stream().forEach((model1) -> {
        hs2.add(model1.getIl());
    });
    al2.addAll(hs2);
    comboIl.addItem(0000);
    al2.stream().forEach((al1) -> {
        comboIl.addItem(al1);
    });
    comboIl.removeItem(0);
    if (il == 0) {
        comboIl.setSelectedIndex(0);
    } else {
        comboIl.setSelectedItem(il);
    }

    selectedItem_Bolme = (String) comboBolme.getSelectedItem();
    selectedItem_Ay = (String) comboAy.getSelectedItem();
    selectedItem_Il = Integer.parseInt(comboIl.getSelectedItem().toString());
    Pojo tempVar;
    sortedList = DBO.salary_Find(selectedItem_Bolme, selectedItem_Ay, selectedItem_Il);
    for (int i = 0; i < sortedList.size(); i++) {
        if (sortedList.get(i).getIsleyir() == 1) {
            sortedList.remove(i);
            i--;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sortedList.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sortedList.size(); j++) {
            if (sortedList.get(i).getCem() == sortedList.get(j).getCem()) {
            }
            if (sortedList.get(i).getCem() > sortedList.get(j).getCem()) {
                tempVar = sortedList.get(j);
                sortedList.set(j, sortedList.get(i));
                sortedList.set(i, tempVar);
            }
        }
    }
    tableModel = new SalaryTableModel(sortedList) {
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            ad = tableModel.getTopic(row).getAd();
            selectedRow = tableModel.getTopic(row).getId();
            row2 = row;
            return (column != 0) && (column != 17);
        }
    };
    table.setModel(tableModel);
    table = autoResizeColWidth(table, tableModel);
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM");
    DatePickerCellEditor datePicker = new DatePickerCellEditor(formatter);
    datePicker.setFormats(formatter);
    date = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(18);
    date.setCellEditor(datePicker);
    table = new RXTable(tableModel);
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
    add(pane);
    table.setSelectAllForEdit(true);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(100);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMinWidth(100);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setMinWidth(100);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setMinWidth(100);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setMinWidth(100);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setMinWidth(100);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setMinWidth(100);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setMinWidth(100);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setMinWidth(100);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(9).setMinWidth(100);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(10).setMinWidth(100);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(11).setMinWidth(100);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(12).setMinWidth(100);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(13).setMinWidth(100);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(14).setMinWidth(100);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(15).setMinWidth(100);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(16).setMinWidth(100);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(17).setMinWidth(100);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(18).setMinWidth(100);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(19).setMinWidth(100);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(20).setMinWidth(100);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(21).setMinWidth(100);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(21).setMaxWidth(10000);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    double x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tableModel.getRowCount(); i++) {
        x += tableModel.getTopic(i).getArtim();
    }
    lblArtiminCemi.setText(String.valueOf((x)));
    double y = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tableModel.getRowCount(); i++) {
        y += tableModel.getTopic(i).getCem();
    }
    lblTotal.setText(String.valueOf((y)));
    comboBolme.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        String selectedBolme = (String) comboBolme.getSelectedItem();
        visible(selectedBolme, ay, il);
        setVisible(false);
    });
    comboAy.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        String selectedAy = (String) comboAy.getSelectedItem();
        visible(bolme, selectedAy, il);
        setVisible(false);
    });
    comboIl.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        int selectedIl = Integer.parseInt(comboIl.getSelectedItem().toString());
        visible(bolme, ay, selectedIl);
        setVisible(false);
    });
    table.getModel().addTableModelListener((TableModelEvent e) -> {
        int row = e.getFirstRow();
        int column = e.getColumn();
        TableModel model1 = (TableModel) e.getSource();
        String columnName = model1.getColumnName(column);
        Object value = model1.getValueAt(row, column);
        Pojo temp;
        sortedList = DBO.salary_Find(selectedItem_Bolme, selectedItem_Ay, selectedItem_Il);
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedList.size(); i++) {
            if (sortedList.get(i).getIsleyir() == 1) {
                sortedList.remove(i);
                i--;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedList.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < sortedList.size(); j++) {
                if (sortedList.get(i).getCem() > sortedList.get(j).getCem()) {
                    temp = sortedList.get(j);
                    sortedList.set(j, sortedList.get(i));
                    sortedList.set(i, temp);
                }
            }
        }
        List<Pojo> list = sortedList;
        Pojo data = list.get(row);
        switch (column) {
            case 0:
                data.setId((int) value);
                break;
            case 1:
                data.setAd((String) value);
                break;
            case 2:
                data.setCins((int) value);
                break;
            case 3:
                data.setBank((Double) value);
                data.setCem(data.getBank() + data.getIlk_maas() + data.getSon_maas() + data.getArtim());
                break;
            case 4:
                data.setIlk_maas((Double) value);
                data.setCem(data.getBank() + data.getIlk_maas() + data.getSon_maas() + data.getArtim());
                break;
            case 5:
                data.setSon_maas((Double) value);
                data.setCem(data.getBank() + data.getIlk_maas() + data.getSon_maas() + data.getArtim());
                break;
            case 6:
                data.setArtim((Double) value);
                data.setCem(data.getBank() + data.getIlk_maas() + data.getSon_maas() + data.getArtim());
                break;
            case 7:
                data.setCem((Double) value);
                break;
            case 8:
                data.setElave_is((int) value);
                break;
            case 9:
                data.setMukafatlandirma((Double) value);
                break;
            case 10:
                data.setQayib_gunu((int) value);
                break;
            case 11:
                data.setDetal_xetasi((Double) value);
                break;
            case 12:
                data.setSatin_alma((Double) value);
                break;
            case 13:
                data.setBolme(value.toString().toUpperCase());
                break;
            case 14:
                data.setAy((String) value);
                break;
            case 15:
                data.setIl((Integer) value);
                break;
            case 16:
                data.setIsleyir((int) value);
                break;
            case 17:
                data.setNe_qeder_isleyib((String) value);
                break;
            case 18:
                try {
                    String time = value.toString();
                    Date date3 = new Date();
                    SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM");
                    Date date4 = format2.parse(time);
                    SimpleDateFormat format3 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM");
                    data.setBaslama_tarixi(format3.format(date4));
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    cal.setTime(date3);
                    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
                    cal2.setTime(date4);
                    int diffYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    int diffMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) - cal2.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    if (diffMonth < 0) {
                        diffMonth += 12;
                        diffYear--;
                    }
                    data.setNe_qeder_isleyib(diffYear + " il " + diffMonth + " ay");
                } catch (NumberFormatException | IndexOutOfBoundsException | ParseException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Salary.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                break;
            case 19:
                data.setBorc((Double) value);
                break;
            case 20:
                data.setYekun_maas((Double) value);
                data.setCem(data.getBank() + data.getIlk_maas() + data.getSon_maas() + data.getArtim());
                data.setYekun_maas(data.getCem() - data.getBorc()
                        - ((data.getCem() / 26) * data.getQayib_gunu()) - data.getDetal_xetasi()
                        + data.getSatin_alma() + ((data.getCem() / 26) * data.getElave_is()));
                break;
            case 21:
                data.setQeyd((String) value);
                break;
        }
        DBO.salary_Update(data, selectedRow);
        visible(bolme, ay, il);
        setVisible(false);
    });
}`
```

Comment: My guess is it's not working because you are auto-resizing your table columns, causing the view not to need a horizontal scrollbar. The default behavior of the `JScrollPane` is to show the vertical and horizontal bars as needed.

Comment: also check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104916/how-to-make-jtable-both-autoresize-and-horizontall-scrollable , also check out its comments since there is some updated info.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to display the full text of the cells instead of an abbreviation, you can use the [Table Column Adjuster](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/). e.g.:

```
String[] columnNames = {"Colum1", "Colum2", "Colum2"};
String[][] data = {
    {"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "-", "-"},
    {"-", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "-"},
    {"-", "-", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"}
};
TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

JTable table = new JTable();
table.setModel(model);
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

TableColumnAdjuster tca = new TableColumnAdjuster(table);
tca.adjustColumns();

JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.add(pane);
frame.setSize(400, 300);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

[image: TableColumnAdjuster example]

You can get the code for the class `TableColumnAdjuster` from http://www.camick.com/java/source/TableColumnAdjuster.java

Answer (score 0):

Found a way )

```
table.setModel(tableModel);
    table = autoResizeColWidth(table, tableModel);
    //table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM");
    DatePickerCellEditor datePicker = new DatePickerCellEditor(formatter);
    datePicker.setFormats(formatter);
    date = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(18);
    date.setCellEditor(datePicker);
    table = new RXTable(tableModel) {
        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
            return getPreferredSize().width < getParent().getWidth();
        }
    };
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
    add(pane);
    //table.setSelectAllForEdit(true);
    //table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(100);
    //table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMinWidth(100);
    //....
    //table.getColumnModel().getColumn(21).setMinWidth(100);
    //table.getColumnModel().getColumn(21).setMaxWidth(10000);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```